# React redux children useContext or a simple select

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've a parent using

```
const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated);
```

whats the best approach using the same selector also

in the child

or using a context provider like

- Parent

  <AuthContext.Provider value={isAuthenticated}>
- Child

  const isAuthenticated = useContext(AuthContext);

Comment: Why not use useSelector in child as well?

Comment: It's up to you. If you're already getting it through Redux, it may be a bit unnecessary to introduce another Context to pass it through. You could even create your own hook for that, e.g. `const useAuthenticated = () => useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you re-use the selector, as it is just a function.

```
export const selectIsAuthenticated = state => state.isAuthenticated;

// Usage
import { selectIsAuthenticated } from './auth-selectors.js'

const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated);
```

Or re-use it as a custom hook:

```
import { selectIsAuthenticated } from './auth-selectors.js'

export const useAuth = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated);
  // more auth related code ...
  return { isAuthenticated };
};

// usage

const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the authentication information the best way would be to use the

```
const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated);
```

at all the places where you need the auth information which is also the purpose of custom hooks in the first places, to have a common reused logic at one single place.

Creating another Context for the same information does not provide any benefit.

In both the cases only the consumers of the context will render whether you use Context again or the Selector hook.

Hence using the useSelector hook at all the places saves you the extra headache of creating the context again which anyway is not providing any extra benefit.